# deathCounter not incrementing

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, int, increment

Hi in this game that i am trying to modify there are 3 different types of enemies all with the same enemyHealth script. in this health script i am attempting to increase a counter every time an enemy dies. the code below shows the enemyHealth class

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int startingHealth = 100;            // The amount of health the enemy starts the game with.
        public bool isDead;                                // Whether the enemy is dead.
        public int deathCount;
        public int currentHealth;                   // The current health the enemy has.
        public float sinkSpeed = 2.5f;              // The speed at which the enemy sinks through the floor when dead.
        public int scoreValue = 10;                 // The amount added to the player's score when the enemy dies.
        public AudioClip deathClip;                 // The sound to play when the enemy dies.


        Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator.
        AudioSource enemyAudio;                     // Reference to the audio source.
        ParticleSystem hitParticles;                // Reference to the particle system that plays when the enemy is damaged.
        CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;            // Reference to the capsule collider.
        bool isSinking;                             // Whether the enemy has started sinking through the floor.


        void Awake ()
        {
            // Setting up the references.
            anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
            enemyAudio = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
            hitParticles = GetComponentInChildren <ParticleSystem> ();
            capsuleCollider = GetComponent <CapsuleCollider> ();

            // Setting the current health when the enemy first spawns.
            currentHealth = startingHealth;
        }


        void Update ()
        {
            // If the enemy should be sinking...
            if(isSinking)
            {
                // ... move the enemy down by the sinkSpeed per second.
                transform.Translate (-Vector3.up * sinkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            }
        }


        public void TakeDamage (int amount, Vector3 hitPoint)
        {
            // If the enemy is dead...
            if(isDead)
                // ... no need to take damage so exit the function.
                return;

            // Play the hurt sound effect.
            enemyAudio.Play ();

            // Reduce the current health by the amount of damage sustained.
            currentHealth -= amount;

            // Set the position of the particle system to where the hit was sustained.
            hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint;

            // And play the particles.
            hitParticles.Play();

            // If the current health is less than or equal to zero...
            if(currentHealth <= 0)
            {
                // ... the enemy is dead.
                Death ();
            }
        }


        void Death ()
        {
            // The enemy is dead.
            isDead = true;
            // Turn the collider into a trigger so shots can pass through it.
            capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;
            deathCount++;
            Debug.Log("Deaths" + deathCount);

            // Tell the animator that the enemy is dead.
            anim.SetTrigger ("Dead");

            // Change the audio clip of the audio source to the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt clip playing).
            enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
            enemyAudio.Play ();
        }


        public void StartSinking ()
        {
            // Find and disable the Nav Mesh Agent.
            GetComponent <UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent> ().enabled = false;

            // Find the rigidbody component and make it kinematic (since we use Translate to sink the enemy).
            GetComponent <Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = true;

            // The enemy should no sink.
            isSinking = true;

            // Increase the score by the enemy's score value.
            ScoreManager.score += scoreValue;
            // After 2 seconds destory the enemy.
            Destroy (gameObject, 2f);

        }
    }
}
```

all of the 3 enemies in the game have this script attached on their prefabs so they behave in the same way, so I cannot see why the counter will not increment when an enemy is destroyed.

when debugging the counter seems to go to 1 and then every kill after that just stays at 1 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is correct. It's a member, so it will existing for each instance of your enemy. You want to track three different healths, right?

So enemy 1 start with 100, enemy 2 with 100, enemy 3 with 100. When enemy 1 gets 20 damage, it goes to 80 and 2,3 stay at 100, right? Why would the counter behave differently then? They all start at 0 and go to 1 when they die.

Either have an upper object (e.g. enemymanager) and have that count the times an enemy die (preferred solution) or use a static variable.

Comment: Hi Andrea, the way that it is set up is that by default the health of an enemy is 100 and then I set it to what I want it to be for the other enemies, I just need the counter to increase whenever an enemy dies, I was under the impression that increasing the deathCounter in this script will affect all instances and work as intended eg each time an enemy dies the counter goes up by 1

Comment: That variable exist - like health - for each instance. And will only go from 0 to 1 as they will die only once. If you want to track all the deaths, as i said, either use a static variable - so it's shared by all instances - or use a enemy manager class

Comment: so if I just change the deathCounter to a static variable then all instances will share it and it should give the behavior I'm looking for? logically it sounds correct? as you can probably tell I am a noob with this so please forgive the incessant questions and i really do appreciate the help

Comment: @PaPaB1nG0 yes, if you declare the variable static, it will become a 'class variable' and will be shared across all instances. Although it will work, generally from a design perspective this probably isn't a good idea for multiple reasons (it breaks a few OOP principles such as encapsulation) and can make debugging your code more difficult